# Jupyter Ipywidgets Export to Static HTML - Widget Javascript not detected

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have built an interactive Jupyter notebook (written in python) with ipywidgets that allows the user to interact with the kernel and filter charts, show dataframes, etc.

The problem I'm running into is that when I export the jupyter notebook to a static HTML file, the widgets disappear. When I try to run it in command line:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute "mynotebook.ipynb"
```

I see:

```
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed or 
enabled properly.
```

Through google-fu, I've found that I need to execute the following command:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

...Which seems to work when I run it in command line:

```
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: ok
```

But I still get the same error when I try to export the notebook to HTML.

Looking around, I see most people are getting this error when they actually try to run a widget in the notebook. This isn't my issue, as I'm able to run widgets within the notebook environment, but am not able to export the resulting notebook into HTML. That's where the `Widget Javascript not detected` messages come up.

Interactivity is great and all, but unless I can expose these widgets, what's the point of interactivity?

Thanks for your help!